# wp_mail PDF attachment is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with the PDF attachment task in mail. Mail is working for me but I am not able to attach PDF with the mail.

There is no issue with the PDF path, because I tried with PNG and JPG images as an attachment, and they are working. I tried a lot with it but still didn't get any solution.

Can anyone please look into the code and give me a solution for this?

Here is my code

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');
//$html2pdf->setModeDebug();
$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
$html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
$pdfName = time().'.pdf';
$invoicePath = WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/uploads/invoice/'.$pdfName;
$html2pdf->Output($invoicePath,'F');

$userInfo = wp_get_current_user();
$userEmail = $userInfo->data->user_email;
$userID =  $userInfo->data->ID;

$attachments = $invoicePath; //array("C:\xampp\htdocs\moca_website\wp-content\uploads\invoice\1482234745.pdf");

$separator = md5(time());
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// boundary 
$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 
$headers[] = 'From: '.get_option( 'blogname' ).' <'.get_option( 'admin_email' ).'>'.PHP_EOL;
$headers[]= "MIME-Version: 1.0".PHP_EOL; 
$headers[]= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary= '".$mime_boundary."' ".PHP_EOL; // see below 
$headers[]= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".PHP_EOL;

$subject = "Invoice";
$content = 'Please <a href="'.$attachmentLink.'">click</a> here for invoice';
wp_mail( $userEmail,$subject, $content, $headers, $attachments="" );
$message = "Your invoice sent to your email";
```

Comment: PDF is already generated or are you generating on the fly? i mean when you are sending email at that time you are generating PDF ?

Comment: First of all  i am creating the PDF before mail send

Comment: I think issues is when email going to sent at that time may be PDF is not generated in your directory.  If you try with static PDF so it will attached successfully. so in this case you have to wait for email send ones pdf is successfully created in your directory.

Comment: and one more thing in your code i seen attachment variable line code is commented.

Comment: I tried  with the static URL of PDF still it is no working, i removed the comment for attachment